# Perl: is assigning [] or {} expensive? How to reset numeric/associative arrays quickly?

Tags: perl, performance, memory-management, reference

I have [a card game](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/) - written in Perl and with few objects, like this one:

```
package PlayingTable;

our (%Games, $Num);

sub new {
        my $pkg   = shift;

        my $game = {
                ID        => ++$Num,
                PHASE     => WAITING,
                KIBITZERS => [],
                PLAYERS   => [],
                INFO      => '',
                RED5      => '',
                TALON     => [],
                TABLE     => {},
                ROUND     => 0,
                PASS_ROUND => 0,
                START     => undef,
                TURN      => undef,
                NPASSED   => 0,
                HOLDER    => undef,
                WHISTER1  => undef,
                WHISTER2  => undef,
                ACTIVE    => undef,
                PASSIVE   => undef,
                SHOW      => undef,
                BEFORE    => undef,
                SUIT1     => undef,
                TRUMP     => undef,
                WINNER    => undef,
        };

        $Games{$Num} = $game;
        bless($game, $pkg);
}
```

and in the objects I have many hash and list references, which I often have to reset. For example, when a game round is over (one case: when all players passed), I will just call **$player->{CARDS} = {};** to reduce the number of cards in the player hand to 0.

My question is **if assigning [] and {} is a good enough practice or if it is too expensive**, because the perl interpreter will malloc (or whatever it does to allocate memory) those new hash and array objects internally (will it really? or is the interpreter clever enough?).

I'm using (and do not want to upgrade) the stock CentOS perl package:

```
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

with CentOS 5.6 / 64 bit, on a 4GB machine and have max. simultaneous 500 players at evenings. My perl process (a non-forking daemon, polling TCP-sockets) uses right now:

```
top - 13:50:07 up 13 days,  3:25,  1 user,  load average: 2.64, 3.36, 3.46
Tasks: 179 total,   2 running, 177 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  :  3.6%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  6.0%us,  1.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 92.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  : 13.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 85.3%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  : 42.7%us,  1.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 54.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.3%hi,  0.7%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   4018280k total,  2831016k used,  1187264k free,   313128k buffers
Swap:  7999472k total,    13612k used,  7985860k free,  1775196k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13685 afarber   15   0  112m  46m 2704 R 41.8  1.2 176:45.14 pref.pl
```

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: I can't write [this](http://www.developer.com/lang/perl/article.php/1554501/Perl-Debunking-the-Speed-Myth.htm) as a complete answer, but I have recently looked through this document, it might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [rules of optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization) are

1. Don't.
2. Don't … yet.
3. Profile before optimizing.

In another comment, you say you don't have performance problems, so you're still at rule 1.

As for how to clear arrays and hashes, there's one potential pitfall to avoid. Good practice is to always return copies of objects' private data. Consider

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package My::Class;

sub new {
  my($class,@a) = @_;
  bless { a => \@a } => $class;
}

sub a {
  my($self) = @_;
  $self->{a};
}

package main;

my $obj = My::Class->new(1, 2, 3);

my $a = $obj->a;
print "@$a\n";

push @$a, qw/ foo bar /;

my $b = $obj->a;
print "@$b\n";
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3
1 2 3 foo bar
```

Returning a reference to private data gives a handle for making uncontrolled and likely surprising modifications.

If your code is sharing references, be sure to *clear the same arrays and hashes* rather than creating references to new ones. Otherwise, everyone else will go on using the old data without knowing anything has changed. In Perl terms, write

```
@{ $game->{PLAYERS} } = ();
```

rather than

```
$game->{PLAYERS} = [];
```

Comment: Ok, maybe a good point. So @{ $game->{PLAYERS} } = (); is better than $game->{PLAYERS} = []; and %{ $game->{CARDS} } = (); is better than $game->{CARDS} = {}; here?

Comment: Also I'm not optimizing, I'm refactoring (had cards as bits in a 32-bits integer, but want to get away from that for various reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is a good practice.

There's a performance problem with Perl on RHEL-based systems, including CentOS. The package that RedHat built is substantially slower than Perl should be. You ought to experiment with ActiveState's build or a new build of Perl (you can build Perl 5.14 in /opt/perl514 if you want, it's not hard) to see if you get better performance.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have performance problems actually. I'm just asking about the quickest way to reset arrays (okay, could set their lengths to 0, but is that needed?) and especially hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I made a search about this because I think it's an interesting question, but I didn't find any exact numbers.

However, here are some articles I've found:

- [A lot about benchmarking and how Perl uses RAM](http://www252.pair.com/comdog/mastering_perl/Chapters/06.benchmarking.html)
- [Some tips on how to write 'faster' apps](http://www.developer.com/lang/perl/article.php/1554501/Perl-Debunking-the-Speed-Myth.htm)
- [Some tools to optimize your programs if you need to](http://dev.perl.hu/blog/2009/05/perl-programmers-shouldnt-care-about-memory-and-cpu-usage.html)